# Recover formatted ext4 partition with file structure that was damage before format

Tags: data-recovery

I have a an 18TB External Hard Drive that I connected to a HDD docker with another HDD. I disconnected the other HDD properly with the safely eject command, but for some reason both disk disconnected at the same time and for some reason when I reconnected the 18TB disk it display a message that It cant be mounted because the File System is corrupted.

I Researched abut this and to repair the file system I could use some command or gparted to check the File System and try to repair it, however, I was very afraid that doing this would corrupt the data files of the disk  and render the data useless. Now I know I should have tried to do this first instead.

I decided to better do a quick format of the disk and then use a recovery tool like r-studio to get the files back. I had not written any new information into the disk, but I have done scans with R-studio and test disk. I know all or at least most of my files are there, but I don't know how to get them back properly. Before doing the quick format I copied the detail information from gparted to may be help me later if I needed. here it is:

```
<i>Filesystem volume name:   EZStore18TB
Last mounted on:          /media/other/EZStore18TB
Filesystem UUID:          e1a36a06-b7cf-4756-8366-6a70f06f299c
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              274661376
Block count:              4394581504
Reserved block count:     219729075
Overhead clusters:        17749129
Free blocks:              2079631492
Free inodes:              273682528
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         2048
Inode blocks per group:   128
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue May  2 02:49:56 2023
Last mount time:          Thu Jun  1 05:11:57 2023
Last write time:          Thu Jun  1 06:25:44 2023
Mount count:              25
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue May  2 02:49:56 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          5429 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      36fcc721-8eee-45e3-99c1-0089baa44cd4
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x727ffe2e</i>

<i>dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
dumpe2fs: Corrupt group descriptor: bad block for inode table while reading journal inode</i>

<i>Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.</i>
```

My first question is. I had not choice but to connect and disconnect the Hard Drive to make the scans of the disk, I am aware that doing this writes some info into the disk is this making the recovery of files more unlikely because is overwriting files from the disk or because is metadata it doesn't overwritten the files?

Second, I have r-studio pro. I did the scan but it doesn't find the file structure or the files. Is it because I should had try to run the file system check to repair the filesystem before, or perhaps this disk is GPT which I am not entirely sure and now I need another recovery tool to recover the files? or may be both.

Can someone please guide me how to may be use the metadata I took before and use r-studio or other program to align the disk properly so that I can get the files in a new scan.correctly.

Can anyone recommend me perhaps another recovery tool that perhaps automate all this so I don't have to input this data because I am afraid to lose all the data doing this. Or what is the best tool to recover this files that will work.

If this doesn't work what will be the best low-level scanning tool I can use to get the Files back( however I would like to try as much as possible to recover the file structure since I have some projects there that without the name It will take me years to reconstruct, leaving this as the last option).

I am aware that to recover the data will take me probably month since this is such a huge hard drive. Unfortunately I have many family videos and pictures in this hard drive that I copied recently that I cherish a lot and may be a low level formatting will help me with that, but I have also some projects that I do really need the file structure to be able to work. Although, the disk is not full may be 6TB are used I know I have to do full scans to recover all the data.

I know my data is there or most of it. Please someone that perhaps had pass for the same trouble help me to recover the files. I do not have thousands of dollar to get this to a recovery center, but I will be patient. Please if someone sees this post and think is all, don't mind I am open to try everything I can and the next few month.

Thanks in advance to anyone that takes the time to help me.